# Ordering the following from smallest to largest in terms of efficiency

Tags: sorting, big-o, time-complexity

I have tried to sort this out from smallest to largest in terms of efficiency but got it wrong.

Any help please?

x<sup>*e*</sup>, *e*<sup>x</sup>, (x+sinx)x<sup>20</sup>, x<sup>*e*</sup>, ln<sup>2</sup>x, xlnx, x + sinx, 13 + 1/x, lgx, 1/x

Comment: I edited your question and see that you have two x^_e_ in your question. Mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you define efficiency? Do you want to know how to sort these regarding their asymptotic complexity? [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

when x grow very big:

- 1/x is near 0
- 13 + 1/x is near 13
- lgx  grow very slow, lg(10000000000) = just a bit more than 33)
- ln²x is slow also, ln²(10000000000) = 530
- x + sinx is approximatively x when x is very big
- xlnx
- x^e is x^2.71828
- (x+sinx)x^20 = x^21 + x^20*sinx, si its almost equal x^21
- e^x is a very fast growing function, e^20 is 4.85*10^8

If so, **1/x < 13 + 1/x < lgx < ln²x < x + sinx < xlnx < x^e < (x+sinx)x^20 < e^x**